# Fetch the row which has the latest occurrence based on multiple ids

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I am attempting to find the last message per user per session. Each message row has the user id and which user session it is (incrementing by 1 for each session)

My table looks like this:

```
user_id | timestamp                  | usermessage   | user_session_id

1       | 2019-08-28 14:50:39.150000 | hi            | 1
1       | 2019-08-28 14:50:40.150000 | goodbye       | 1
1       | 2019-09-01 10:50:39.150000 | hello again   | 2
1       | 2019-09-01 11:50:39.150000 | goodbye again | 2
2       | 2019-07-09 07:53:56.680000 | hello         | 1 
2       | 2019-07-10 09:23:16.100000 | hi there      | 2
```

I am looking to retrieve the last message (latest timestamp) each user posted per session. So my expected output would be something like this

```
user_id | timestamp                  | usermessage   | user_session_id
1       | 2019-08-28 14:50:40.150000 | goodbye       | 1
1       | 2019-09-01 11:50:39.150000 | goodbye again | 2
2       | 2019-07-09 07:53:56.680000 | hello         | 1 
2       | 2019-07-10 09:23:16.100000 | hi there      | 2
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Postgres, I would recommend `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (user_id, user_session_id) t.*
from t
order by user_id, user_session_id, timestamp desc;
```

In Postgres, this is usually the most efficient method for doing this type of query.  For best performance, you want an index on `(user_id, user_session_id, timestamp desc)`.

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()`

```
select * from     
(select *,row_number() over(partition by user_id, user_session_id order by timestamp desc) rn
from table_name
) a where a.rn=1
```